# Javascript : Getting object property in function

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have created simple javascript program and I have created one popup named myWin in that pop up I have defined 2 hyperlinks when I click on hyperlink particular function should be called and it should open particular url and url I am referring from movie object which I defined in main window  but somehow I am not able to call function from hyperlink. When I click on hyperlink it should open new window and it should get url from movie object. Could anyone help me to solve an error.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

</style>
<title>lab 8</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myWin = window.open("", "myWin", "height=500, width=500,location,menubar,toolbar,status,resizable");



    function movie(movie_title, website_title, actor, website_actor)
        {
            this.the_movie_title = movie_title;
            this.the_website_title = website_title;
            this.the_actor = actor;
            this.the_website_actor = website_actor;

        }



        var myMovie = new movie("Before she was Wonder Woman, she was Diana, princess of the Amazons, trained to be an unconquerable warrior. Raised on a sheltered island paradise, Diana meets an American pilot (Chris Pine) who tells her about the massive conflict that's raging in the outside world. Convinced that she can stop the threat, Diana leaves her home for the first time. Fighting alongside men in a war to end all wars, she finally discovers her full powers and true destiny.", 

            "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0451279/",

            "Gal Gadot is an Israeli actress, singer, martial artist, and model. She was born in Rosh Ha'ayin, Israel, to an Ashkenazi Jewish family. Her parents are Irit, a teacher, and Michael, an engineer, who is a sixth-generation Israeli. She served in the IDF for two years, and won the Miss Israel title in 2004.", 

            "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2933757/?ref_=tt_cl_t1");


    myWin.document.write(

        +"  <script type='text/javascript'>"

        +"      function movieWin() {"
        +"  var movieWin = window.open(\"movie.website_title\" , \"movieWin\", \"height=500, width=500,location,menubar,toolbar,status,resizable\");"
        +"      }"

        +"      function actorWin() {"
        +"  var actorWin = window.open(\"movie.actor" , "actorWin", "height=500, width=500,location,menubar,toolbar,status,resizable\");"
        +"     <p style='color: green; font-size: 17px;'>"
        + movie.actor
        + "<a href='javascript:(\""+movie.website_actor+"\");'>Click for more info</a>"
        +"      </p>"
        +"      } "
        +"  <\/script>"

        );

     myWin.document.write(
    +"  <script type='text/javascript'>"
    +   "<body style='background-image : url(lab8_images/back.png)'>"
    +   "<h1 style= 'text-align: center; color: white; font-family: monospace; font-size: 200%'> What about this movie? </h1>"
    +    '<br/>' + '<br/>' +'<br/>' 
    +  "<p style = 'font-family: monospace; font-size: 150%; color: #ffffff; text-align:center; text-decoration: none'> <a href = 'javascript:movieWin()'> CLICK HERE TO ACCESS TO THE MOVIE WINDOW </a><br></p>"
    +   "<p style = 'font-family: monospace;font-size: 150%; color: #ffffff;  text-align: center; text-decoration: none'> <a href ='javascript:actorWin();'> CLICK HERE TO ACCESS TO THE ACTOR WINDOW </a><br></p>"
+"  <\/script>"
        );

</script>

</head>
<body background = lab8_images/back.png>

</body>
</html>
```